About the J-method of interpolation
In the classic text of J.Bergh and J.Lofstrom, Interpolation Spaces, the $J$-method of real interpolation defines a functor in the following way: For $0<\theta<1$ and $1\leq q\leq \infty$ we define the functor $J_{\theta,q}$ which associates to every compatible couple $\overline{E}=(E_0,E_1)$ the space $(E_0,E_1)_{\theta,q;J}$ as the space of elements $x\in \sum(\overline{E})$ which can be represented by $$x=\int_0^\infty \frac{u(t)}{t}\,dt,$$ (with convergence in $\sum(\overline{E})$), where $u$ is a measurable function taking values on $\Delta(\overline{E})$ and satisfies $$\Phi_{\theta,q}\left(J(t,u(t))\right)<\infty.$$ We define $$||x||_{\theta,q;J}=\operatorname{inf}_{u}\Phi_{\theta,q}\left(J(t,u(t))\right),$$ where the infimum is taken over all the measurable functions $u$ taking values on $\Delta(\overline{E})$ and satisfying $\Phi_{\theta,q}\left(J(t,u(t))\right)<\infty$. Here $$J(t,x)=\operatorname{max}\{||x||_{E_0},t||x||_{E_1}\},$$ for $t>0$ and $x\in E_0\cap E_1$. In the proof of Theorem 3.2.2 which states that the $J$-method is an exact interpolation functor of exponent $\theta$ the author states that for every admisible operator $T$ we have $$Tx=T\left(\int_0^\infty u(t)/tdt\right)=\int_0^\infty Tu(t)/tdt,$$ without any commentary or observation, which seems to be very arbitrary. Researching i found that it could be related with Bochner integrals (something that the authors do not comment in any moment and its not trivial), which verify the interchanging property with bounded operators. The problem is that these integrals are defined on Banach spaces and in principle, the $J$-method is a functor on normed spaces, not only Banach ones. Is a mistake of the authors and the J-method is only definable on Banach spaces? Or there's something I'm missing.
Thanks in advance!

This seems like a fun question. Actually, one could already ask what the integral in the representation for $x$ means, no? I any case, my guess would be that one could probably consider step functions $u$ only. There is a corresponding remark in Triebel, Interpolation Theory, Function Spaces, Differential Operators, Chapter 1.6.1.

The exposition of the $J$-method in the book by R. A. Adams and J. J. F. Fournier, Sobolev Spaces (Elsevier, 2002) indeed assumes $E_0$ and $E_1$ to be Banach spaces and yes, the Bochner integral is in fact used therein. There is a discrete version of the $J$-method which circumvents the use of the Bochner integral (see e.g. Theorem 7.15, pp. 213-215 of ibid.), but I'm not sure if it can be extended to $E_0,E_1$ just normed. Btw, the Adams-Fournier exposition is mainly based on the book by P. L. Butzer and H. Berens, Semi-Groups of Operators and Approximation (Springer, 1967).

(continued) I have the impression that the discrete method does carry through to $E_0,E_1$ just normed, but that of course has to be checked. However, when it comes to considering admissible operators $T$, the commutation of $T$ with the Bochner integral is tacitly used by Adams-Fournier as well (see Theorem 7.23, pp. 220-221 of ibid.). One would need first to try combining both theorems just quoted to see how the proof of the latter theorem carries through in the discrete version of the $J$-method, and then check if the ensuing argument carries through to the normed case.

Honestly, I find it amusing (and concerning) that Bergh-Löfström are so cavalier with the use of the Bochner integral, for e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2880662/integration-in-normed-vector-spaces

Yes... Bergh-Lofstrom's book have many lacks of rigour... Im writing a Master's thesis on interpolation with the intention to be a sort of hitchhiker's guide on interpolation with the rigour that books usually misses, i want to upload it to arxiv, hope you can read it one day! Thank you very much for the answers, I'm 90% sure that the discrete version works on the normed spaces category, i will work on it
